# how to edit this baseactivity to get admob Interstial ads at launching time only

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

The baseactivity of this code display admob interstial ads and refresh after five minutes but how to edit this code so that Interstial ads display only at the launching time, no refreshing of the interstial ads. The interstial ads need to display only at the app launching time, where to edit the code.

```
package com.samplecodes.app;

import java.io.File;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import com.samplecodes.app.R;
import com.samplecodes.app.constant.ConstantVariables;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    AdView adView;
    String AD_UNIT_ID = "";
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAds = null;
    private int postdelay = 5;
    private Handler myHandler = null; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_header);

        mPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        int old_versioncode = mPrefs.getInt(ConstantVariables.VERSION_CODE, 0);
        int v = 0;
        try {
            v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
            if (v != old_versioncode) {

                // Delete old database file
                File dbFile = getDatabasePath(ConstantVariables.DATABASE_NAME);
                dbFile.deleteOnExit();

                editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putInt(ConstantVariables.VERSION_CODE, v);
                editor.commit();
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        this.setupInterstitialAds();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sharebtn:
            Intent intentShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intentShare.setType("text/plain");
            intentShare
                    .putExtra(
                            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            getString(R.string.app_name)
                                    + " /r/n "
                                    + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samplecodes.app");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare, "Share"));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        } 
    }

    protected void setupInterstitialAds() {
        // Create an ad.
        this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this);
        this.interstitialAds.setAdUnitId("");//  AD_UNIT_ID
        // Set the AdListener.
        this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() { 
                myHandler = new Handler();
                myHandler.postDelayed(runRepeatIntertitialAds, postdelay * 1000*60);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        "Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown. onAdFailedToLoad "
                                + errorCode);
            }
        });
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(deviceid).build();

        this.interstitialAds.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    private Runnable runRepeatIntertitialAds = new Runnable()
    {
            public void run()
            {
                showInterstitial();
                //write here whaterver you want to repeat
                myHandler.postDelayed(this, postdelay * 1000*60);
            }
    };

    protected void setupAdmob() {
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(deviceid).build();

        // AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    protected void share() {

        ImageView shareImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
        shareImg.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /** Called when the Show Interstitial button is clicked. */
    public void showInterstitial() {

        if (this.interstitialAds.isLoaded()) {
            this.interstitialAds.show();
        } else {
            Log.e("", "Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.");
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) { 
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if (myHandler != null) {
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(runRepeatIntertitialAds);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `#onAdLoaded` to be:

```
private boolean alreadyShownInterstitial;

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() { 
    if (!alreadyShownInterstitial) {
        alreadyShownInterstitial = true;
        showInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Just note that Google doesn't take kindly to out of flow display of interstitial ads like this, and you may well get your account banned. You are much better off displaying the interstitial at a natural break point in your app.